# C# code not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started learning the language C# from the book "Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity 3d". I have been working through the book fine up until page 47 when it gives me the following code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LearnScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int number1 = 2;
    public int number2 = 3;
    public int number3 = 4;


    void start()
    {
        AddTwoNumbers(number1, number2);
        AddTwoNumbers(number1, number3);
        AddTwoNumbers(number2, number3);
    }

    void update()
    {

    }

    void AddTwoNumbers (int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        int result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        Debug.Log(result);
    }
}
```

What the book says it is meant to do is output the answers to the `AddTwoNumbers` method, but when I click play on unity the console is empty.

I have attached the code to the main camera so that shouldn't be a problem there. If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong it would be appreciated. I don't want to move on with the book until I get this little bit of code to work. If it makes any difference I am using Unity version 5.2.3.

Comment: well... weird. looks right except for the case letters. try Start() and Update(), and make sure it is attached on some object in the scene!

Comment: Yeah there is no start() method being called in the code..

Comment: C# uses cap letter on front of methods. start is not Start.

Comment: In this case, it would be start() as the code snippet does not show Start()..

Comment: @ゴスエンヘンリ Thanks a lot for the help. I never realised the names had to be in caps

Comment: @Flukiercobra41 Remember, C# is case sensitive!  `start != Start`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make sure this is attached to some object in the scene.

Second, rename:

```
void Start()
{
    AddTwoNumbers(number1, number2);
    AddTwoNumbers(number1, number3);
    AddTwoNumbers(number2, number3);
}
```

`Start()`, not `start()`.

Also it is `Update()`, not `update()`.

C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help